# Best color space for finding similar colors

Tags: c++, image, colors, rgb, grayscale

What color space I should use if I am trying to find all the pixels of similar color ? I tried using GrayScale and ran DFS at the point in the image where I want to find similar pixels that are connected to it but seems like it is not the correct way. Which color space should I use that will give me help me finding the pixels of similar color in a that are connected starting from some point in image. Initially I have RGB image.

Comment: You probably want to use a [Delta E](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT) computation, which is almost always done in the L*a*b* color space.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what "similar" means to you. Colours similar for a computer can be very differently perceived by a human.

OTOH, HSV model could fit rather nice, as it's pretty intuitive for non-robots.

Comment: Exactly; you need to define what "similar" means first, then find the right color model.

Answer (score 1):

I once got good results using the [Lab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) color space and computing the [color difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) (CIE76 was good enough for me).

From [the Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#Advantages):

> > > Unlike the RGB and CMYK color models, Lab color is designed to approximate human vision.

So if your definition of similar is: "they look similar", I'd go with Lab.

Answer (score 1):

Lab is a very good color space but I understand that it is a bit more difficult to use due to its nonlinearity and generality.

HSV is a very good color space if you are interested in the hue and are dealing with images where you want to easily eliminate shadows and reflections.

YCrCb is a very good (and not as sophisticated as Lab) color space if you are interested in approximating human visual perception. It takes into account that for humans, R, G, and B components produce stronger and weaker stimuli.

Answer (score 0):

check this thread [Python - Find similar colors, best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863810/python-find-similar-colors-best-way)

and the answer is :http://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the color space HSV(Hue, Saturation, Value or Brightness) .

After convert your image to HSV you must set the channels Saturation and value with a common value like 100 or any other that stress the colors. With that transformation the Hue will be the only channel with some variation and this should be enough to show only the similar colors with little variations.

If you want reduce the intervals, you can generate on histogram of the channel Hue with the interval that you want, and calculate the difference with the other histograms. The result of that calculation will be the distance between the colors.