# Function to get coordinates of a color not working

Tags: python

It's now working, the result is: "None"

```
blue = [70, 238, 255]

def FindColor(color):
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    for x in range(1, 400):
        for y in range(1,400):
            px = image.getpixel((x, y))
            if px[0] == color[0] and px[1] == color[1] and px[2] == color[2]:
                return (x, y)

FindColor(blue)
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The question is why isn't it working... I recently started python and dont really know how to define the question because I dont know what is the problem

Comment: Oh you meant `not` - you have a typo in the question. By the way what is this function supposed to be doing?

Comment: provide some other details.

Comment: It's supposed to find the x and y coordinates of a color.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of blue is way too exact.
I mean, [71, 238, 255] (70 --> 71) would look just the same to our eyes, but the computer would notice the difference.

There exists a program called pynche which can change RGB to colour name in English for Python. 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/pynche/ColorDB.py

Btw, maybe you should think of using a list instead of returning only the coördinates of the first match with your color.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing color directly, try calculating distance between then.

The code below is collected form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863952/10305444).

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char r, g, b;
} RGB;

double ColourDistance(RGB e1, RGB e2)
{
  long rmean = ( (long)e1.r + (long)e2.r ) / 2;
  long r = (long)e1.r - (long)e2.r;
  long g = (long)e1.g - (long)e2.g;
  long b = (long)e1.b - (long)e2.b;
  return sqrt((((512+rmean)*r*r)>>8) + 4*g*g + (((767-rmean)*b*b)>>8));
}
```

Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).