# Python Opencv Tell the color name when get rgb from image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I need to get the color of a pixels in a specifict region of image.
Im using this script in python:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')

color = image[100,50]

print(color) # gives me the RGB color (12,156,222)
```

and if a need to get the hex of it:

```
hex = (color[0] << 16) + (color[1] << 8) + (color[2])
```

my question is: There is a way to tell me what color is it? `(12,156,222)`
thank you.

Comment: "color" meaning as a hue in degrees on a color wheel, or color described as a word?

Comment: Not all rgb colors have names. You would have to create a list of color names and their associated rgb values and find the closest named color to your rgb values. See the CSS list of named colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to solve this problem
using `webcolor` i was able to detect the closest color

```
import webcolors
import time
start = time.time()
def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = None
    return actual_name, closest_name

requested_colour = (255, 0, 0)
actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)

print("Actual colour name:", actual_name, ", closest colour name:", closest_name)
print("Tempo: ", time.time() - start)
```

if anyone have another bester method please send here ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can look it up at: https://shallowsky.com/colormatch/index.php?r=12&g=156&b=222

[spoiler alert: "DeepSkyBlue3"]

In general, you want to start with

1. a list of name → R,G,B values, and
2. a distance function

Then it's a matter of computing distance between each of those and your target value.
Return the corresponding name for whichever list entry has minimum distance to target.

A previous SO answer offers such an algorithm: [Python - Find similar colors, best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863810/python-find-similar-colors-best-way#62675780)

Using Euclidean distance (L2 norm) in some random color space is less than principled,
though often sufficient.
If you want to sweat the details, consider relying on https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io.
(You might even want to discuss maintainership with the author.)

If "perceptually similar" matters to you, definitely use Lab: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space

Comment: its to advanced for me :( could you help me or give me some python example?

Comment: I cited a brief python solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863810/python-find-similar-colors-best-way#62675780